# Logic on Oracle Tree

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Below is the structure for the table :

REF_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER
REF_TYPE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER
PARENT_REF_ID          NUMBER
REF_VALUE     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)

Following Query had achieved the following result, but I might need the result :

```
WITH
    refs (ref_id,
          ref_type_id,
          parent_ref_id,
          ref_value)
    AS
        (SELECT 501, 1, NULL, 207 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 502, 2, 501, 4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 503, 3, 502, 1 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT r.ref_id as starting_ref_id,
           TRIM (
               ',' FROM
                   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (
                          CASE r.ref_type_id
                              WHEN 1 THEN 'article '
                              WHEN 2 THEN 'par '
                              WHEN 3 THEN '('
                              WHEN 4 THEN 'point '
                              WHEN 5 THEN 'sous '
                              WHEN 6 THEN NULL
                              WHEN 8 THEN NULL
                              ELSE '/'
                          END
                       || r.ref_id,
                       ','))    AS ref_label
      FROM refs r
     WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR r.parent_ref_id = r.ref_id;
```

Output from the query :

STARTING_REF_ID                   REF_LABEL

---

```
           501 article 501
           502 par 502,article 501
           503 (503,par 502,article 501
```

**Expected result:**

STARTING_REF_ID                   REF_LABEL

---

```
           501 article 501
           502 article 501,par 502
           503 article 501,par 502,(503,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added reverse to the select

```
WITH
refs (ref_id,
      ref_type_id,
      parent_ref_id,
      ref_value)
AS
    (SELECT 501, 1, NULL, 207 FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 502, 2, 501, 4 FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 503, 3, 502, 1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT r.ref_id as starting_ref_id,
       TRIM (
           ',' FROM
           reverse( --reverse path order (also reverts letters in words)
               SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (
                 
                     reverse( --put letters in words and numbers in ids back in the right order
                          CASE r.ref_type_id
                          WHEN 1 THEN 'article '
                          WHEN 2 THEN 'par '
                          WHEN 3 THEN '('
                          WHEN 4 THEN 'point '
                          WHEN 5 THEN 'sous '
                          WHEN 6 THEN NULL
                          WHEN 8 THEN NULL
                          ELSE '/'
                      END
                   || r.ref_id),
                   ',')
                   
                   ) )   AS ref_label
  FROM refs r
 WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR r.parent_ref_id = r.ref_id
```

[image: Result:]

Comment: The solution does what the OP requested. There are two issues with it though. First, `reverse` is not documented (and therefore not supported); this is OK for non-critical applications, but shouldn't be used in production in important applications. Second, the OP's existing query is flawed to begin with - it doesn't start from the root and traverse the tree down from there, it goes in the opposite direction. This Answer offers an additional patch along the same flawed solution, instead of fixing the root cause of the whole thing (fixing the query itself).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all in a very unnatural way.

You should start with the root (where parent id is `null`) and go "down" from it, not the other way around. Then you don't need a `where` clause, you need a `start with` clause; and the `connect by` condition must go the opposite way. Then you don't need to make any other changes to the query.

Like this:

```
WITH
    refs (ref_id,
          ref_type_id,
          parent_ref_id,
          ref_value)
    AS
        (SELECT 501, 1, NULL, 207 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 502, 2, 501, 4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 503, 3, 502, 1 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT r.ref_id as starting_ref_id,
           TRIM (
               ',' FROM
                   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (
                          CASE r.ref_type_id
                              WHEN 1 THEN 'article '
                              WHEN 2 THEN 'par '
                              WHEN 3 THEN '('
                              WHEN 4 THEN 'point '
                              WHEN 5 THEN 'sous '
                              WHEN 6 THEN NULL
                              WHEN 8 THEN NULL
                              ELSE '/'
                          END
                       || r.ref_id,
                       ','))    AS ref_label
      FROM refs r
START WITH parent_ref_id is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR ref_id = parent_ref_id;
```